# Using nohup and & on remote Mac OS X causes process to become idle?

Tags: gnu-screen, macos, nohup

I am running some code on a remote server (an iMac), and I want the process to keep running after I log out.

So, I am using nohup and &. However, the process becomes idle when I leave (log off) and resumes when I return. I have tried with screen as well, and it does the same thing. I also tried to use the 'caffeinate' command, but that did not help. I really need it to continue working after I leave.

Is there anything else I can try or look into?